# Como criar propriedades dinamicamente em C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

Em JavaScript é fácil criar um objeto com novas propriedades.

```
var obj = {
  "propriedade1" : "valor",
  "propriedade2" : "valor"
}
```

É possível fazer algo parecido em C#?

```
var lista = new List<Object>();

 foreach (var item in umaOutraList)
 {
      lista.Add(new Object()
      {
          nome = item.Nome //Essa linha não funfa.
      });
 }
```

Comment: Bem @bigown em termos de solução, eu havia usado a dica do Fernando mesmo. Mas com sua resposta agora pude entender mais a fundo o conceito. Mais importante do que fazer funcionar é saber por que está funcionando... E também usar a melhor solução. Obrigado!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As respostas atuais não simulam exatamente o que ocorre com o JS. Pode até atingir um resultado semelhante (e não igual), mas de uma forma bem diferente. Assim simula corretamente:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Dynamic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
        obj.propriedade1 = "valor1";
        obj.propriedade2 = "valor2";
        WriteLine(obj.propriedade1);
        WriteLine(obj.propriedade2);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ULtMYf). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p3DDGj). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/Expando.cs).

[Documentação do `ExpandoObject()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Desta forma pode adicionar e remover membros no objeto como pode fazer no JS. Pode manipular tudo **dinamicamente** como é no JS, com uma sintaxe padrão da linguagem. Assim o objeto é criado sem ter uma classe como modelo, mas ele se comporta como se fosse um objeto normal do .NET.

Pode não ser necessário para o AP, mas a premissa da pergunta indica isto.

Comment: Isso é chamado de Reflexão?

Comment: Isto não é a reflexão em si, mas o mecanismo que permite isto acontecer é a reflexão com alguma ajuda do compilador.

Answer (score 12):

Se isso é realmente necessário em seu código sem ter uma `class` realmente, então você pode usar [`dynamic` do C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd264741.aspx) ao invés de `object`, fazendo algo assim:

```
IList<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(new {
    nome = "Fernando",
    idade = 26,
});
```

Comment: Nao e' preciso `dynamic` neste cenario. So' e' preciso `dynamic` se a intencao for mais tarde ler as propriedades (e, nesse caso, o melhor e' mesmo criar uma classe propria em vez de usar anonymous types). Se nao for preciso ler as propriedades, o melhor e' usar `List<object>` em vez de `List<dynamic>`

Comment: @dcastro, sim `dynamic` não é necessário se não desejar obter o valor da propriedade posteriormente, nesse caso `object` já seria suficiente. Mas só citei o `dynamic` por ser mas prático e ter essa finalidade. E também não tenho conhecimento sobre grandes problemas em utiliza-lo ao invés de `object`. Mas sua colocação é válida.

Answer (score 5):

Basicamente isso é o [`Anonymous Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

Exemplo:

```
var umaOutraList = new List<String>();
umaOutraList.Add("1");
umaOutraList.Add("2");

var novaLista = umaOutraList.Select(x => new {
    Nome = x
});

foreach (var item in novaLista)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Nome);
}
```

### Saída:

> 1
>
> 2

### [CSharpPad DEMO](http://csharppad.com/gist/9b9d4d5932daaafb5910)

Answer (score 0):

Utilizar um objeto anônimo deve funcionar, para isso basta usar `new { nome = "" }` ao invés de usar `new Object { nome = "" }`.

Utilizar `dynamic` como o @Fernando sugeriu na resposta dele também deve funcionar.