# Como criar uma variável onde acesso suas propriedades via string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, classes, propriedade

Gostaria de acessar por *string* as propriedades de um objeto: (EXEMPLO 1)

```
var cor = casa["cor"];
var tamanho = casa["tamanho"];
```

Ao invés de acessar assim: (EXEMPLO 2)

```
var cor = casa.cor;
var tamanho = casa.tamanho;
```

Criando dessa forma eu acesso pelo EXEMPLO 2:

```
var casa = new {
    cor = "verde",
    tamanho = 2000
}
```

Como que eu criaria o objeto casa para conseguir acessar como no EXEMPLO 1?

Comment: Usa jSon então...

Comment: Explique um pouco melhor o que deseja. Seria isto? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90671/101

Comment: Reformulei @bigown, veja se está um pouco mais claro.

Comment: Você quer acessar das duas formas? Ou quer acessar só da forma de cima?

Comment: Só da forma de cima, via string

Comment: O meu entendimento foi de que você quer acessar por string as propriedades de um objeto, correto!? Neste caso acredito que tenha que utilizar Reflection.

Comment: Postei uma resposta utilizando `Reflection` que te permite utilizar exatamente como no seu exemplo. O objeto possui as propriedades com suas respectivas tipagens e podem ser lidas e escritas identificando-as por string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A primeira forma pura e simples pode ser obtida com um [`Dictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0)

```
var casa = new Dictionary<string, object>();
casa.Add("cor", "verde");
casa.Add("tamanho", 2000);
var cor = casa["cor"];
var tamanho = casa["tamanho"];
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mDM1AD). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0LvPQa). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/InitMember.cs). Usei a sintaxe de inicialização.

Eu evitaria fazer isto já que o objeto fica sem tipagem. O primeiro tipo da estrutura indica o tipo da chave. No caso `string` cai bem. Como o tipo do valor pode contar vários tipos, então tem que generalizar e usar `object`. Ou seja, toda entrada no dicionário aceitará qualquer valor.

Uma outra possível solução é usar o [`ExpandoObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que dá o dinamismo e pode acessar com as duas sintaxes (não simultâneamente):

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.cor = "verde";
obj.tamanho = 2000;
WriteLine(obj.cor);
WriteLine(obj.tamanho);
var obj2 = (IDictionary<string,object>)obj;
WriteLine(obj2["cor"]);
WriteLine(obj2["tamanho"]);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nNaQWx). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U1VzT7). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/WithExpando.cs).

Qualquer solução de declara uma classe normal e tentar acessar desta forma é desnecessária. Até poderia fazendo reflexão, mas provavelmente estaria usando a ferramenta errada para o problema.

Comment: O que tem de errado na resposta?

Comment: O meu entendimento foi de que ele quer acessar por string as propriedades de um objeto, não uma estrutura chave valor.

Comment: Mas seu entendimento pode estar errado. Se não tem certeza é melhor não votar. Peça esclarecimento para ele. Pelo que eu eu entendi ele votou na resposta, então ele achou boa.

Comment: @MFedatto E com a aceitação do AP, parece que meu entendimento está correto. Não saia distribuindo negativo porque você entendeu uma coisa diferente. O negativo é para coisas erradas. Eu acho que as outras respostas dão soluções confusas e provavelmente não atendem o que o AP quer, pelo menos não de forma simples. Nem por isso eu vou negativá-las.

Comment: Concordo com seu ponto de vista. Retirei o negativo.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode utilizar indexadores conforme exemplo da própria documentação da Microsoft (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/2549tw02.aspx):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Casa> lstCasas = new List<Casa>()
            {
                new Casa("Azul", 50),
                new Casa("Amarela", 70),
                new Casa("Branca", 90)
            };

            foreach (Casa _casa in lstCasas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Casa cor: {0}, tamanho: {1}", _casa["cor"], _casa["tamanho"]);
            }
            Console.Read();

            Casa _casaTemp = lstCasas[0];
            Console.WriteLine("Exception" + _casaTemp["Erro"]);
        }
    }

    public class Casa
    {
        private string cor;
        private int tamanho;

        public Casa(string _cor, int _tamanho)
        {
            this.cor = _cor;
            this.tamanho = _tamanho;
        }

        public object this[string strCampo]
        {
            get
            {
                switch (strCampo.ToLower())
                {
                    case "cor":
                        return this.cor;
                    case "tamanho":
                        return this.tamanho;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentException("Propriedade inválida");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Uma abordagem mais genérica, conforme citado pelo @Cigano Morrison Mendez seria utilizando Generics. Conforme demonstrado abaixo, uma ressalva para esta abordagem é que deve-se usar propriedades e não atributos e os métodos get das propriedades devem ser públicos:

```
public class Casa
    {
        public string cor { get; private set; }
        public int tamanho { get; private set; }

        public Casa(string _cor, int _tamanho)
        {
            this.cor = _cor;
            this.tamanho = _tamanho;
        }

        public object this[string strCampo]
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValorPelaPropriedade(strCampo);
            }
        }

        private object GetValorPelaPropriedade(string strNomePropriedade)
        {

            PropertyInfo _propInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(strNomePropriedade);

            if (_propInfo == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Propriedade inválida");

            return _propInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bem interessante, mas acho que ficaria ótimo se `public object this[string strCampo]` fosse implementado usando um comportamento mais genérico. +1.

Comment: Tem como usar reflection para pegar a propriedade, vou ajustar aqui

Comment: Agora sim, eu diria que é a melhor resposta até então.

Answer (score 2):

Basta converter o objeto para dicionário. [Esta resposta tem o método abaixo que pode servir bem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13602785/1314276):

```
public static KeyValuePair<object, object> Cast<K, V>(this KeyValuePair<K, V> kvp)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<object, object>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}

public static KeyValuePair<T, V> CastFrom<T, V>(Object obj)
{
    return (KeyValuePair<T, V>) obj;
}

public static KeyValuePair<object, object> CastFrom(Object obj)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        if (type == typeof (KeyValuePair<,>))
        {
            var key = type.GetProperty("Key");
            var value = type.GetProperty("Value");
            var keyObj = key.GetValue(obj, null);
            var valueObj = value.GetValue(obj, null);
            return new KeyValuePair<object, object>(keyObj, valueObj);
        }
    }

    throw new ArgumentException(" ### -> public static KeyValuePair<object, object> CastFrom(Object obj) : Erro : argumento obj deve ser do tipo KeyValuePair<,>");
}
```

Uso:

```
var dicionario = CastFrom(objeto);
```

[Ou ainda esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23225770/1314276), que opinativamente achei melhor por ser uma extensão de qualquer objeto:

```
public static class ObjectToDictionaryExtension
{
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object source)
    {
        return source.ToDictionary<object>();
    }

    public static IDictionary<string, T> ToDictionary<T>(this object source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            ThrowExceptionWhenSourceArgumentIsNull();

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, T>();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(source))
            AddPropertyToDictionary<T>(property, source, dictionary);
        return dictionary;
    }

    private static void AddPropertyToDictionary<T>(PropertyDescriptor property, object source, Dictionary<string, T> dictionary)
    {
        object value = property.GetValue(source);
        if (IsOfType<T>(value))
            dictionary.Add(property.Name, (T)value);
    }

    private static bool IsOfType<T>(object value)
    {
        return value is T;
    }

    private static void ThrowExceptionWhenSourceArgumentIsNull()
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source", "Unable to convert object to a dictionary. The source object is null.");
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var dicionario = objeto.ToDictionary();
```

Comment: O meu entendimento foi de que ele quer acessar por string as propriedades de um objeto, não uma estrutura chave valor.

Comment: Pois bem. Precisa converter pra um dicionário primeiro. Através do objeto nativo não tem como.

Comment: Tem com Reflection.

Comment: Bom, então coloque sua resposta. Estou ansioso para saber como.

Comment: Feito. Exemplo completo e funcional postado como resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Para acessar as propriedades ou métodos de um objeto você precisa utilizar `Reflection`. Você até pode desenvolver uma classe híbrida encapsulando uma estrutura chave-valor (`Dictionary`) para armazenar os valores por nome e implementar as propriedades `Cor` e `Tamanho` atribuindo e recuperando valores através das chaves, mas a solução tecnicamente mais aderente à sua pergunta é utilizando `Reflection`. Segue um exemplo funcional que atende a sua necessidade:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Casa casa = new Casa() { Cor = "Verde", Tamanho = 2000 };
            Wrapper wrapperCasa = new Wrapper(casa);

            wrapperCasa.SetPropetyValue<string>("Cor", "Vermelho");
            wrapperCasa.SetPropetyValue<int>("Tamanho", 2500);

            Console.WriteLine(wrapperCasa.GetPropetyValue<string>("Cor"));
            Console.WriteLine(wrapperCasa.GetPropetyValue<int>("Tamanho").ToString());
        }
    }

    class Casa
    {
        public string Cor { get; set; }
        public int Tamanho { get; set; }
    }

    class Wrapper
    {
        private object obj { get; set; }
        private Type tipo { get; set; }

        public Wrapper(object obj)
        {
            this.obj = obj;
            this.tipo = obj.GetType();
        }

        public void SetPropetyValue(string prop, object value)
        {
            this.SetPropetyValue<object>(prop, value);
        }

        public void SetPropetyValue<T>(string prop, T value)
        {
            this.GetPropertyInfo(prop).SetValue(this.obj, value, null);
        }

        public object GetPropetyValue(string prop)
        {
            return GetPropetyValue<object>(prop);
        }

        public T GetPropetyValue<T>(string prop)
        {
            return (T)this.GetPropertyInfo(prop).GetValue(this.obj, null);
        }

        private PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(string propriedade)
        {
            return this.tipo.GetProperty(propriedade);
        }
    }
}
```

Criei um encapsulador (`Wrapper`) apenas pra facilitar a utilização, pois o que ocorre de fato é a utilização do objeto principal (`Casa`) sem tipagem, como um `object`, e utilizar `Reflection` com um objeto `Type` para invocar os métodos e propriedades desejadas.