# Como pegar atributo dinamicamente

Tags: c#, .net, classes, reflexão, propriedade

Como eu faria o seguinte código do PHP em C#?

```
class teste{
    public $x = 10;
    public $y = 10;
}

$n = new teste();
$a = "y";

print_r($n->{$a});
```

Note que o dinamismo está na variável `$a`, na qual se eu trocar para `x` me retorna o valor de `teste->x`.

Isso é possível?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp e https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @bfavaretto funcionou, apenas tive que cuida com o cast que estava gerando erro :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível obter isto através de reflexão. C# é uma linguagem estática, então não tem porque ela ter facilidades prontas para o acesso direto. Mas é possível criar uma classes com alguns métodos de extensão para facilitar o uso:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var teste = new Teste();
        teste.ListProperties();
        WriteLine(teste.GetPropValue<int>("y"));
        var teste2 = new Teste2();
        teste2.ListFields();
    }
}

public class Teste {
    public int x { get; set; } = 10;
    public int y { get; set; } = 10;
}

public class Teste2 {
    public int x = 10;
    public int y = 10;
}

public static class ObjectExt {
    public static void ListProperties(this object obj) {
        foreach(var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            WriteLine($"{prop.Name} = {prop.GetValue(obj, null)}");
        }
    }
    public static void ListFields(this object obj) {
        foreach(var field in obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)) {
            WriteLine($"{field.Name} = {field.GetValue(obj)}");
        }
    }
    public static T GetPropValue<T>(this object value, string propertyName) {
        if (value == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("value"); }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) { throw new ArgumentException("propertyName"); }
        PropertyInfo info = value.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        return (T)info.GetValue(value, null);
    }
    public static FieldInfo GetFieldInfo(this Type objType, string fieldName, BindingFlags flags, bool isFirstTypeChecked = true) {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = objType.GetField(fieldName, flags);
        if (fieldInfo == null && objType.BaseType != null) {
            fieldInfo = objType.BaseType.GetFieldInfo(fieldName, flags, false);
        }
        if (fieldInfo == null && isFirstTypeChecked) {
            throw new MissingFieldException(String.Format("Field {0}.{1} could not be found with the following BindingFlags: {2}", objType.ReflectedType.FullName, fieldName, flags.ToString()));
        }
        return fieldInfo;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JHWFrG). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ClhjfB). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/GetField.cs).

Modifiquei o código para ficar mais idiomático no `Teste` e mais parecido com o exemplo usado no PHP no `Teste2`. O ideal em C# é preferir a forma de propriedades e não com campos públicos (que pode ser usado em casos específicos, se houver motivo e souber porque está fazendo isso). Claro, dá para criar do jeito que quiser, mas a base é esta.

Lembre-se que se quiser ter a mesma semântica das classes do PHP, é preciso usar outro tipo de estrutura. No PHP a classe na verdade é um dicionário de dados, não é uma estrutura estática. Em C# dá para criar uma uma classe baseada em um dicionário de dados e manter uma sintaxe mais limpa através do [`ExpandoObject`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92090/101). Desta forma a reflexão fica embutida na própria classe. Você pode acessar com a sintaxe de classe, ou com a sintaxe de dicionário, que é o que foi usado no exemplo do PHP.

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.x = 10;
obj.y = 10;
WriteLine(((IDictionary<string, object>)obj)["y"]);
```

Como dá para percebrr o que deseja é pegar os campos e não atributos que nem existem no código, use os [termos corretos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Comment: `using static` é tipo uva passa na ceia de natal, sempre tem alguém que gosta, rs.