# Como criar um Custom Attribute?

Tags: c#, atributos

Já algum tempo que estou tentando entender o conceito de *custom attribute* do C#. Acho ele meio parecido com o sistema de *decorators* do Python. Mas não estou entendendo muito bem.

Eu dei uma lida em um [artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827091/Csharp-Attributes-in-minutes#Whatareattributesandwhydoweneedit) do CodeProject, mas ainda não ficou claro. Entendi que para criar um `CustomAttribute`, é necessário criar uma classe que herde de `Attribute`. Mas digamos que eu queira criar um `CustomAttribute` para validar a propriedade do tipo `int` de uma classe, para permitir somente números pares. Nesse caso onde ficaria o código de validação?

Um exemplo seria bom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro há um engano em achar que os atributos do C# são equivalentes aos *decorators* do Python, o funcionamento de ambos são bem diferentes.

O atributo é apenas uma informação estática, é um [metadado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101). Se eles não são chamados por algum mecanismo eles fazem nada. Essa chamada é feita através de [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/101) ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105236/101)), por isso difere do Python.

Claro que é possível usar esse mecanismo para facilitar a criação de um *decorator*. De fato isso é feito em uma [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2966730/221800). Uma [comparação direta com Python é feita aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15323009/221800).

Você pode criar um método no atributo para realizar a validação em si, mas ela não será feita só porque o atributo está presente em algum elemento do código. Sua invocação será em algum outro local, feita pelo programador usuário do atributo ou por algum *framework* que automatiza isso para o programador final. [Essa resposta mostra bem isto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927067/221800).

Tem um [exemplo de como funciona](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21463/Simple-Attribute-Based-Validation) e [um mais completinho](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31954/An-attribute-based-approach-to-business-object-val) no CodeProject. O próprio [.NET tem um exemplo](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/RangeAttribute.cs,f73565aee622e8de) bem completo de como pode ser um atributo semelhante (note que o [`IsValid()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.isvalid?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads) não se chama sozinho, assim como os demais métodos da classe).

Seu exemplo:

```
[TypeUsage(int)] //atributo hipotético
class EvenAttribute : Attribute {
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid(int value) {
        return value % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/AttributeUsage.cs).

Este atributo hipotético `TypeUsage` que pode ser usado por alguma ferramenta para garantir que o seu atributo personalizado só seja usado em uma propriedade do tipo `int`. Este atributo precisaria ser criado por você e a ferramenta que faz a verificação também.

Obviamente, como mostra os exemplos *linkados* acima, é possível fazer algo mais sofisticado, pode ser algo dentro de uma mecanismo maior, com contratos específicos estabelecidos, aí depende da necessidade, mas genericamente tá aí o exemplo.

[Exemplo prático de uso em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127867/101).

Comment: Minha ideia era criar algo automático, onde eu trato em apenas um lugar e o efeito se aplica em qualquer objeto criado, deixando o tratamento transparente para quem for consumir a classe, ou seja, qualquer classe que "decore" uma propriedade tipo int com o Attribute `TypeUsage` e quando um objeto dessa classe for instanciado com um valor não par, uma exceção seria lançada. Mas isso deveria ser transparente para o consumidor da classe, ele não deve precisar tratar. Eu poderia usar os padrões get e set, mas e se eu precisasse do mesmo efeito em várias outras classes, eu teria que repetir código.

Comment: Minha experiência que isto nem sempre funciona como o desejado a não ser em sistemas simples ou pouco flexíveis, a não ser que se dê vários escapes, o que obviamente complicado o mecanismo. A automação pode ser feita por um método que lide com isso, em geral, para ficar transparente, será pela criação de um *framework*. Acho que eu não devia ter usado o `TypeUsage`, você não entendeu a função dele aí, ele é um atributo usado na criação de outro atributo. Faça de conta que ele não existe, até entender melhor o resto. Lançar exceção? Tá, ok, é uma opção, mas eu provavelmente não faria isto.

Comment: Pode ser transparente para a classe consumidora que usa o atributo, mas a chamada da execução da validação precisa ocorrer em algum lugar, por isso costuma ser usado em *frameworks* que tornam as coisas meio "mágicas", como você quer. Talvez você precise pensar em um caso mais concreto do que deseja e fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: Não, não o que eu preciso é exatamente isso. Eu já faço isso em python através de metaclasses. Lá eu tenho várias classes com atributos que não podem ser negativos. Lá o tratamento fica dentro de uma metaclasse, então todas as classes que precisam do tratamento fazem uso da metaclasse que eu criei. Evitando assim replicar código.
Eu achei que o recurso de CustomAttribute do C# me permitiria fazer algo parecido.

Comment: Uma correção, no primeiro cometário eu citei erradamente "Attribute TypeUsage" quando na verdade é Attibute `EvenAttribute`

Comment: Ele ajuda, mas não sozinho. Você precisaria criar o mecanismo semelhante ao das meta-classes por conta própria ou usar algum *framework* pronto que faça isto para você.

Comment: Você sabe me indicar algum? De preferência MS

Comment: Depende do que precisa. O ASP.Net MVC faz isto bem automático.