# Executar construtor de um Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, construtor, atributos

Como faço para chamar o construtor de um atributo antes do construtor da classe decorada?

Por exemplo, tenho o meu atributo:

```
using System;    
namespace T.WinForm
{
    public class TesteAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public TesteAttribute()
        {
               Console.WriteLine("Executei o construtor do atributo..."); 
        }
    }
}
```

E tenho a classe decorada pelo atributo anterior:

```
using System;
namespace SimT.WinForm
{
    public partial class FrmMenuPrincipal : SimTForm
    {
        [TesteAttribute]
        public FrmMenuPrincipal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Console.WriteLine("Executei o construtor da classe...");
        }
    }
}
```

Gostaria que ao executar esse código, a sequencia da escrita do console ficasse dessa forma:

1. Executei o construtor do atributo...
2. Executei o construtor da classe...

A intenção é fazer algo parecido com o `AuthorizeAttribute` do ASP.Net MVC.

Estou tentando fazer isso utilizando uma aplicação WinForms com .Net 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Entenda como funciona esse decorador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119024/101).

Para chamar todos atributos de todos os métodos é preciso ter um código em algum lugar que os atributos sejam "chamados". Isto é feito através de reflexão que lerá os [metadados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101) existentes. A execução pode ser feita de várias formas.

Uma forma simples para este caso é ter um método que invocado no construtor de `SimTForm` ou uma classe base acima dele, ou seja tem que ser manual, mas não precisa ser manual em todos os lugares que usar, pode encapsular a execução em uma classe base que sempre será usada e abstrair várias coisas, entre elas a chamada dos atributos. Assim a simples herança "automatiza" a execução dos construtores de atributos.

Não é um boa ideia chamar o construtor diretamente, porque isso fará perder completamente a utilidade do atributo. Se você chama explicitamente o construtor não precisa de mais nada para decorar o método.

Então a classe base deverá "listar" todos os métodos que são do seu interesse (dá para filtrar de várias formas, leia a documentação e use a criatividade) e invocar seus atributos.

Código que pega os métodos da classe atual:

```
this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

Documentação do [`GetMethods()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetMethods_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_).

Para chamar os atributos:

```
method.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Documentação do [`GetCustomAttributes()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Reflection_MemberInfo_GetCustomAttributes_System_Boolean_).

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/atjL8V). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wdvCzB). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/ConstructorAttribute.cs).

Obviamente precisa adaptar à sua necessidade. Lembrando que tem outras formas de obter o mesmo resultado e talvez para ocaso do AP alguma delas seja mais adequada.

Comment: Eu percebo esta solução. Mas agora ficamos com um problema novo: Quem é que deve obter os atributos da classe? Segundo o OP é a própria classe. O que quer dizer que a classe tem informação suficiente para instanciar o atributo necessário. Normalmente os atributos são para consumo de outras bibliotecas, ou pela própria biblioteca do .NET (por exemplo `Serializable`). Por isso eu percebo esta solução, percebo até que possa ser usada, mas não acho que ela seja a melhor para este caso.

Comment: Pode ser, ele poderia usar algo externo, poderia fazer o WinForms trabalhar nisso, mas nem imagino se isso é simples ou complexo de fazer. Esta forma, é simples. O ideal é que o WinForms já o fizesse. De uma certa forma essa classe base dele é uma extensão do WinForms. Se é a melhor pra ele, eu não sei dizer já que não conheço toda situação dele.Os atributos devem ser consumidos. Quem fará isto não importa pra eles. Importa para quem está usando-os. No caso tentei, na medida do possível, simular o resultado que ele obtém no ASP.Net MVC que já sabe o que fazer com o atributo que ele falou.

Comment: Pois e era exactamente essa poeira que eu não queria que ficasse escondida na sua resposta. Consumir atributos que são declarados pela própria aplicação normalmente dá bastante trabalho e podem envolver muitas outras operações com reflexão.

Comment: Ah sim, ele precisa construir ou ampliar as funcionalidades de um *framework*. Os atributos servem para melhor nesses casos.

Comment: Olá senhores. Tentei abstrair a minha duvida e acabei gerando uma discussão bem interessante onde aprendi bastante. No entanto o que eu estava procurando era perfeitamente essa solução, pois minha ideia é, conforme vocês apontaram, consumir outras bibliotecas sem que eu tenha que deixar exposto na classe.