# Como listar métodos de uma classe em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, classes, método, reflexão

Mais uma vez eu tenho que falar isso: venho do PHP e estou aprendendo C# agora.

Eu geralmente gosto de listar os métodos que a classe tem, pois eu sempre fazia isso em PHP, para testar ou debugar.

```
$a = new ArrayObject();

get_class_methods($a);
```

E no C#? Como posso fazer para poder listar os métodos de um objeto?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isto é feito com reflexão. Especificamente com o método [`GetMethods()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetMethods_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_) da classe [`Type`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). É possível filtrá-los como quiser, ou através do próprio método ou depois com o *array* do tipo [`MethodInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) gerado por ele.

Exemplos:

```
objeto.GetType().GetMethods() //resolve o tipo em tempo de execução
typeof(TipoAqui).GetMethods() //resolve o tipo em tempo de compilação
```

Exemplo real:

```
foreach (var method in typeof(String).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)) {
    WriteLine(method.Name);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/w6SA0R). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ixPjny). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/ListMethods.cs).

Neste caso estou pegando todos os métodos de instância públicos e mostrando o nome simples deles. Vários dados do método podem ser pegos, consulte documentação para ver tudo o que pode usar.

Obviamente que alguns dos membros da classe `MethoInfo` possuem informações mais complexas que uma simples *string*, ou um booliano (várias propriedades são assim para indicar uma qualidade do método - em geral tem relação com a forma como o método foi declarado), pode ter um outro *array* com informações sobre outros membros do método, por exemplo, os parâmetros existentes nele, os os atributos dele, como pode ser visto em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127867/101).

Como todas estas informações estão em coleções, é muito comum usar o LINQ para filtrar do jeito que deseja.

Ele usa os metadados dos tipos existentes no arquivo *assembly* para informar isto. Não é algo mágico, não busca em documentação, é fato real do tipo. Dá para pegar virtualmente qualquer informação que deseja sobre os códigos do .NET, seus ou de terceiros.

Note que só pega os membros implementados no tipo. Se desejar os método que o tipo tem acesso porque herdou dos demais e não foram sobrescritos, tem que pegar do tipo base (tem método que ajuda fazer isto).

É possível pegar todos os membros do tipo, não só os métodos. Consulte a documentação apresentada acima.

Fiz um [exemplo que pega alguns dados do método](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XOaFgV). Ele está bem simples e não trata erros, então digite o nome completo do tipo (incluindo o *namespace*). É uma base do que seria uma parte de um descompilador.

Comment: Vou testar usando o modo interativo do C#, que aprendi na outra resposta. Valeu, bigown. Tá me ajudando a evolur no C#

Comment: Ótima junção de coisas. Se eu estiver com paciência eu faço um código legal para listar o método de uma forma bem organizada.

Answer (score 12):

Cara, usa o `Type.GetMethods`, retirei a resposta do próprio StackOverflow gringo e funciona, pelo menos aqui.

[StackOverflow Gringo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198417/generate-list-of-methods-of-a-class-with-method-types)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
         ShowMethods(typeof(DateTime));
    }

    static void ShowMethods(Type type)
    {
        foreach (var method in type.GetMethods())
        {
            var parameters = method.GetParameters();
            var parameterDescriptions = string.Join
            (", ", method.GetParameters()
                         .Select(x => x.ParameterType + " " + x.Name)
                         .ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ({2})",
                          method.ReturnType,
                          method.Name,
                          parameterDescriptions);
        }
   }
}
```

A saída vai ser isso aqui:

```
System.DateTime Add (System.TimeSpan value)
System.DateTime AddDays (System.Double value)
System.DateTime AddHours (System.Double value)
System.DateTime AddMilliseconds (System.Double value)
System.DateTime AddMinutes (System.Double value)
System.DateTime AddMonths (System.Int32 months)
System.DateTime AddSeconds (System.Double value)
System.DateTime AddTicks (System.Int64 value)
System.DateTime AddYears (System.Int32 value)
System.Int32 Compare (System.DateTime t1, System.DateTime t2)
System.Int32 CompareTo (System.Object value)
System.Int32 CompareTo (System.DateTime value)
System.Int32 DaysInMonth (System.Int32 year, System.Int32 month)
```

Comment: Gostei da resposta e percebi que, não só os métodos são listados, mas também os argumentos. Mas, se não se importar com minha sinceridade, a resposta falta mais detalhes, explicando o uso, pois, no meu caso, já tenho experiência com programação, mas uma pessoa que está começando agora ficaria sem entender.

Comment: kkkkk Sem problemas, eu apenas dei uma olhada no stack overflow gringo pra te responder porque sinceramente nunca tive a necessidade de listar os métodos de uma classe. Geralmente se quero debugar ou descobrir algo sobre os métodos o InteliSense do Visual Studio me ajuda com isso.