# Como atribuir uma classe ao todo e não só os atributos separadamente?

Tags: c#, .net, classes, instanciar-objeto

Tenho um método construtor de classe que quando chamado faz uma consulta numa outra classe de banco de dados que me retorna a mesma classe do método construtor(**só que com os dados atribuidos**), exemplo:

```
public Invoice(int id)
{
   CallDB db = new CallDB();
   Invoice invoice = db.ReturnInvoice(id);
   this.Filial = invoice.Filial;
   this.UserProfileModel = invoice.UserProfileModel;
   this.DataEmissao = invoice.DataEmissao;
   this.DataVencimento = invoice.DataVencimento;
   this.ID = invoice.ID;
}
```

Eu não gostaria de ficar utilizando o `this` "300 mil" vezes, seria possível fazer algo parecido com isso?

```
public Invoice(int id)
{
   CallDB db = new CallDB();
   Invoice invoice = db.ReturnInvoice(id);
   this.Invoice = invoice ; //estou atribuindo a classe como um todo ao invés de cada atributo separadamente
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem como por vias normais.

E parece que tem várias coisas erradas aí, começando por essa classe que não parece ser o que ela descreve. É até difícil dar uma direção correta por estar com todo fundamento errado.

Claro que você pode fazer o `ReturnInvoice()` já retornar o objeto montado, mas aí você estará fazendo a mesma coisa que já faz no construtor original, só que em outro método. E pior, no método errado que só deveria tratar do banco de dados.

Existe uma solução com [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154462/101), porém não costuma ser recomendado. Me parece ser só para reduzir a digitação e não é um bom uso para isto. E se precisa disto talvez C# não seja a linguagem adequada para esta solução.

Com a reflexão poderia ler a [estrutura dos objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101) e fazer um [laço que pega os dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129060/101) do retorno do banco de dados e atribua nos membros da classe `Invoice`.

Em alguns casos pode facilitar a reflexão se usar certas convenções, mas torna complicado fazer o sistema que não pode fugir delas, não compensa.

Também pode usar um [`Dictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) ou um [`ExpandoObject`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68085/101), mas novamente, aí use uma linguagem dinâmica.

Em C# prefiro uma solução de [*scaffolding*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119731/101) (em C# 9 isso é até mais facilitado) ou fazer manualmente.

Uma reestruturação da arquitetura geral pode dar um solução melhor.

Comment: Como o outro colega disse, está errada a organização né... vou dar uma estudada nas suas respostas citadas(que por sinal são sempre FODAS) e vou aplicar o correto, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse cenário, você teria que fazer a chamda para o objeto dessa forma:

```
Invoice obj = new Invoice(1);
```

correto ?

Sugiro que crie um método estático que retorne o objeto:

```
public class Invoice
{
   public Invoice()
   {
     //...construtor padrão
   }

   public static Invoice SelectById(int id)
   {
       CallDB db = new CallDB();
       return db.ReturnInvoice(id);
   }
}
```

E então faria a chamada:

```
Invoice obj = Invoice.SelectById(1);
```

---

porém... sugiro rever a estrutura do seu código, pois dentro da classe você está tendo acesso a camada de dados, isso está gerando um alto acoplamento e baixa coesão o que não é certo e tornará o código mais complexo e de difícil manutenção.

Comment: Rovann está errado eu ter esse acesso aos dados dentro da classe?

Comment: Eu utilizo MVC, eu faria esse acesso aos dados dentro do controller?

Comment: sim, sempre no controller