# Gerar Objeto com valores de um resource file

Tags: c#

Tenho um `Resource File` com os seguintes valores:

```
Name:     Value:
Teste1    TesteUm
Teste2    TesteDois
```

E leio da seguinte forma:

```
 ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("MyResource",
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());


               var value = rm.GetString("Teste1");
```

Porem gostaria de gerar um objeto dinâmico com os valores algo que eu pudesse acessar da seguinte forma:

```
Resource.Teste1
// retorno TesteUm
```

Sem ter que acessar pela nome em string do valor que eu quero pegar.

Existe alguma forma? seja com reflection ou qualquer outra tecnologia ?

Comment: E qual seria o motivo? Que vantagem espera ter?

Comment: Cara, estou passando diversas constantes que estão espalhadas e repetidas nas classes, para um resource file, e quero evitar que outro programador tenha de entrar neste arquivo e ficar procurando por alguma constante que seja a que ele procura, a ideia era retornar o objeto com os dados deste arquivo e tratar eles como se fosse um ENUM, e no caso que for adicionado mais dados ao resource ele ja preencheria meu objeto dinamicamente, ou seja evitaria manutenção.

Comment: o unco trabalho seria de adicionar um novo registro no meu arquivo de resource e assim ele seria refletido diretamente no meu objeto.

Comment: Pra fazer direito mesmo acho que só com geração de código, você lê o arquivo e gera a classe partido dele. Pode usar um `ExpandoObjeto`, mas só fica mais bonitinho, a vantagem é mínima. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68085/101 ehttps://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/265893/101

Comment: ```Properties.Resources.Teste1```