# Pegar valores de uma lista dinâmica

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, lista

Tenho uma lista do tipo `dynamic`:

```
private List<dynamic> listServicos = new List<dynamic>();
```

E está sendo populada desse jeito:

```
listServicos.Add(new { Codigo = txtCodServico.Text, Servico = txtNomeServico.Text, Quantidade = txtQuantidadeServico.Text, Preco = txtPrecoUniServico.Text });
```

Gostaria de pegar os valores da `lista`, mas não estou conseguindo. Estava tentando desse jeito:

```
foreach (var listServico in listServicos)
{                
    var codigo = listServico.Codigo;               
}
```

O Visual Studio acusa erro:

[image: SS]

Comment: Qual erro ele está acusando?

Comment: @Ricardo Pergunta editada!

Comment: Leonardo, você pode falar mais sobre o projeto? Eu fiz um projeto aqui com um código copy paste do seu e funcionou com todos os frameworks que usei, você fez alguma migração de MVC 2 para 3 por exemplo? Qualquer coisa que tenha sido feita nele pode ser a causa, porque o código funciona...

Comment: @Ricardo agora eu que fiquei curioso em saber como o seu funcionou. Todos os testes que eu fiz não funcionou. Veja errado: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7EyQ0n

Comment: Estranho, no fiddle não funciona, se você criar um projeto novo de console na sua maquina e colocar exatamente o seu código ele funciona... Eu ainda acredito que o problema seja alguma coisa do ambiente.

Comment: @Leonardo você realmente precisa que a lista tenha elementos dinâmicos, ou seja, eles precisam mudar dua estrutura em tempo de execução, ou na verdade foi a solução que adotou para ter um tipo anônimo, mas ele não precisa ser dinâmico?

Comment: @bigown na verdade foi uma solução que adotei. Não precisa ser totalmente dinamico

Comment: @Leonardo eu estou achando que já te dei uma solução melhor na resposta. `dynamic` deve ser usado em último caso. Tem que ter certeza que a solução só pode ser dada em *runtime*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu ainda não achei uma solução mais adequada, só uma usando [`ExpandoObject`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68085/101):

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.Codigo = "Código";
obj.Servico = "Serviço";
obj.Quantidade = "Quantidade";
obj.Preco = "Preço";
var listServicos = new List<dynamic>{ obj };
WriteLine(listServicos[0].Codigo);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ikuviB). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EVW93Y). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/GetItemList.cs).

Eu fico pensando se realmente precisa disto. Pode ser que a solução seja mais simples que isto. É raro alguém precisar de algo realmente dinâmico.

Esta pode ser a solução:

```
var list = Enumerable.Empty<object>()
             .Select(r => new { Codigo = "Codigo", Servico = "Servico", Quantidade = "Quantidade", Preco = "Preco" })
             .ToList();
list.Add(new { Codigo = "Codigo", Servico = "Servico", Quantidade = "Quantidade", Preco = "Preco" });
WriteLine(list[0].Codigo);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Bz6tME). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4V6Mr5). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/GetItemList2.cs).

Outra solução é generalizar ao invés de dinamizar:

```
public static void Main() {
    var list = ToAnonymousList(new { Codigo = "Codigo", Servico = "Servico", Quantidade = "Quantidade", Preco = "Preco" });
    WriteLine(list[0].Codigo);
}
public static IList<T> ToAnonymousList<T>(params T[] items) => items;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4xPmzL). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BGQVRn). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/GetItemList3.cs).

Achei estas [no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15749445/221800).

Sem precisar de um método auxiliar:

```
var list = new[] { new { Codigo = "Codigo", Servico = "Servico", Quantidade = "Quantidade", Preco = "Preco" } }.ToList();
WriteLine(list[0].Codigo);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0EJRin). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RJs1kp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/GetItemList4.cs).

Answer (score 0):

**1 -** Adiciona a referencia a **Microsoft.Csharp**.

Caso já tenha a referencia, remove e insere de novo.

Olha [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11725576/3517631), acredito que possa te ajudar.

**2 -** Outra possível solução é mudar o framework de 4.5 para 4.5.1. ([Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26511502/3517631))
Basta ir no Web.config e alterar:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

para:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

rebuild.

**3 -** Uma outra tentativa é mudar o `Copy Local = True` para referencia da `Microsoft.CSharp`

Comment: Adicionei a referência e ainda não deu certo, e também não posso alterar a versão do framework do projeto =/

Comment: Qual o seu framework atual?

Comment: A versão do framework é 4.0

Comment: O problema não é esse. É que a variável não é dinâmica de fato, vou ver se consigo dar uma resposta plausível.

Comment: Hum, vamos esperar a resposta do @bigown. Não entendi bem qual seria o problema.

Comment: Fico no aguardo @bigown

Comment: Tá difícil entender o que está errado, mas não vou desistir tão fácil.

Comment: Criei um projeto do zero aqui com o seu código, consegui rodar com todos os frameworks, tenta o número 3 que coloquei agora na resposta.