# Como criar uma classe em tempo de execução?

Tags: c#, .net, classes, reflexão, dynamic

Como criar uma classe em tempo de execução, ou *runtime*, dinamicamente, a partir de um `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, por exemplo, com C#?

```
Dictionary<string, string> dicionario = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dicionario.Add("nome", "string");
dicionario.Add("idade", "int");
dicionario.Add("telefone", "string");
dicionario.Add("cpf", "string");
```

O `TKey` seria o nome das propriedades a serem criadas na classe, já o `TValue`, seria o tipo.

Comment: Classe dinâmica ou estática? Que versão do C# está usando?

Comment: Você aceitou uma resposta que gera uma estática, então não entendi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resposta curta: usando [`System.Reflection.Emit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit(v=vs.110).aspx).

Resposta longa: [É esta resposta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862241/1314276), mas não vou apenas colar ela pra você aqui. Vou explicar o princípio.

Primeiro você precisa definir o construtor dinâmico de tipos. A resposta o define abaixo (eu modifiquei um pouco com algumas coisas):

```
private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder(string libraryName = "MainModule", string typeSignature = "MyDynamicType")
{
    var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature); // Aqui você vai definir o nome da classe dinâmica
    AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(libraryName); // Aqui vai definir em qual Class Library sua classe dinâmica vai estar

    TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature,
            TypeAttributes.Public |
            TypeAttributes.Class |
            TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
            TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
            TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
            TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
            null);
    return tb;
}
```

A seguir, podemos colocar o método que cria propriedades. Ele precisa do `TypeBuilder` montado previamente para funcionar:

```
private static void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
{
    FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

    PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
    MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
    ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

    getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
    getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr =
        tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
          MethodAttributes.Public |
          MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
          MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
          null, new[] { propertyType });

    ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
    Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
    Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

    setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
    setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
    setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
    propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
}
```

Provavelmente você terá que modificar seu dicionário para receber um `Type` ao invés de `string`.

A seguir, o método que compila o dicionário na classe dinâmica:

```
public static Type CompileResultType(Dictionary<string, Type> dicionario) // Repare que já mudei aqui pra você
{
    TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder(); // Aqui constrói a classe num Assembly "MainModule.dll", classe "MyDynamicType". 
                                       // Parametrize da forma que achar melhor. 
    ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> chaveValor in dicionario)
        CreateProperty(tb, chaveValor.Key, chaveValor.Value);

    Type objectType = tb.CreateType();
    return objectType;
}
```

Por fim, o método estático que invoca todos os outros:

```
public static object CreateNewObject(Dictionary<string, Type> dicionario)
{
    var myType = CompileResultType(dicionario);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
}
```

Uso:

```
var meuObjetoCriadoDiamicamente = MyTypeBuilder.CreateNewObject(dicionario);
```

Answer (score 3):

Dependendo do seu objetivo existem soluções melhores para fazer isso. Criar com [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/506768/101) quase sempre não é uma boa ideia mais.

Uma das formas de fazer isso é usar o mecanismo do [Roslyn](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) para [gerar código em tempo de execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15428/101). Literalmente você tem o compilador à sua disposição para transformar texto em código nativo, podendo até mesmo gerar classes novas que podem ser usadas no seu código.

Mas tem uma questão a ser analisada. Se o seu código não sabe que classe é essa então ele não tem como fazer nada. Se ele sabe, então não tem porque gerar a classe em tempo de execução. Mesmo que precise de alguma personalização da classe, tem técnicas mais simples na própria linguagem para fazer isso sem recorrer a mecanismos mais avançados. Quase sempre essa necessidade não existe de fato.

Outra forma mais recente e que pode ser bem interessante em alguns cenários é a de geração de código. Com [*source generator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) você pode criar a classe em tempo de desenvolvimento mesmo e não em tempo de execução, portanto pode não ser o que deseja. Mas quase sempre que precisa de criação de classe automaticamente via código é só o que realmente necessita, não precisa gerar em *runtime*.

Ele permite que uma classe ou outros códigos sejam gerados no momento da compilação baseando-se em algum outro código ou fonte. E faz mais sentido porque aí o seu código pode usar essa classe de forma adequada, robusta e eficiente. Ele permite a automação da criação da classe que fica disponível para o código, assim evita o trabalho da criação, que está propensa a erros, e não perde nada, como acontece quando cria de fato a nova classe em tempo de execução.

Novamente, repense se precisa disto, e tente usar um mecanismo mais simples. Talvez só queira personalizar uma classe dinamicamente com [`ExpandoObject()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90671/101), ou só precise de polimorfismo ou algum padrão de projeto conhecido que atinja o objetivo.

Tem forma de usar o .NET que a reflexão como era conhecida nem é aceita mais. Reforço que em qualquer código, reflexão quase nunca é a solução.

Artigos interessantes:

- [Qual é a diferença entre metaprogramação e reflexão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276112/101)
- https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/dynamic-class-creation-roslyn
- https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Jun/07/Runtime-CSharp-Code-Compilation-Revisited-for-Roslyn
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/47219017/221800
- https://www.infoq.com/articles/CSharp-Source-Generator/
- https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md
- https://github.com/amis92/csharp-source-generators

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).